# How do you run an Openshift Docker container as something besides root?

Tags: docker, openshift

I'm currently running Openshift, but I am running into a problem when I try to build/deploy my custom Docker container.  The container works properly on my local machine, but once it gets built in openshift and I try to deploy it, I get the error message.  I believe the problem is because I am trying to run commands inside of the container as root.

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00058: Error retrieving pid file /run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

My Docker file that I am deploying looks like this -

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER me<me@me>
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y ansible && yum clean all -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/dockerFileBootstrap.git
RUN ansible-playbook "-e edit_url=andrewgarfield edit_alias=emmastone site_url=testing.com" dockerAnsible/dockerFileBootstrap.yml
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
COPY supervisord.conf /usr/etc/supervisord.conf
RUN rm -rf supervisord.conf
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
EXPOSE 80 443
#CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Ive run into a similar problem multiple times where it will say things like `Permission Denied on file /supervisord.log` or something similar.

How can I set it up so that my container doesnt run all of the commands as root?  It seems to be causing all of the problems that I am having.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Openshift has strictly security policy regarding custom Docker builds.

Have a look a this [OpenShift Application Platform](https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin-custom-docker-builder/)

In particular at point 4 into the FAQ section, here quoted.

> **4. Why doesn't my Docker image run on OpenShift?**
>
> Security! Origin runs with the following security policy by default:
>
> Containers run as a non-root unique user that is separate from other system users
>   They cannot access host resources, run privileged, or become root
>   They are given CPU and memory limits defined by the system administrator
>   Any persistent storage they access will be under a unique SELinux label, which prevents others from seeing their content
>   These settings are per project, so containers in different projects cannot see each other by default
>   Regular users can run Docker, source, and custom builds
>   By default, Docker builds can (and often do) run as root. You can control who can create Docker builds through the builds/docker and builds/custom policy resource.
>   Regular users and project admins cannot change their security quotas.
>
> Many Docker containers expect to run as root (and therefore edit all the contents of the filesystem). The Image Author's guide gives recommendations on making your image more secure by default:
>
> Don't run as root
>
> Make directories you want to write to group-writable and owned by group id 0
>   Set the net-bind capability on your executables if they need to bind to ports <1024
>
> Otherwise, you can see the security documentation for descriptions on how to relax these restrictions.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, ill be sure to look into it.  Appreciate the reference

Comment: You can relax the restriction with `oc adm add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default` (give the default service account in the current namespace the ability to use the "anyuid" SCC).

Comment: @Clayton I get an "Error from server (Forbidden): User "xxx" cannot get securitycontextconstraints at the cluster scope"

Comment: Changing security context constraints requires cluster admin rights. It cannot be done as a project admin or normal user.

Answer (score 8):

Although you don't have access to root, your OpenShift container, by default, is a member of the root group. You can change some dir/file permissions to avoid the `Permission Denied` errors.

If you're using a Dockerfile to deploy an image to OpenShift, you can add the following RUN command to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN chgrp -R 0 /run && chmod -R g=u /run
```

This will change the group for everything in the /run directory to the root group and then set the group permission on all files to be equivalent to the owner (group equals user) of the file. Essentially, any user in the root group has the same permissions as the owner for every file.

Comment: I wish I could give you +100 points for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run docker as any user , also root (and not Openshift default build-in account UID - `1000030000` when issuing this two commands in sequence on command line oc cli tools
`oc login -u system:admin -n default` following with `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default -n projectname` where projectname is name of your project inside which you assigned under your docker